# Flash colour in entire Excel window

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro to flash up a visual cue when the user opens a workbook, based on some conditions describing the workbook's state.

What I would like to do is fill the entire screen/ the cell area/ the excel border theme with a colour that doesn't affect cell formatting or the contents of anything (it is only temporary).
My current approach is to make a shape to fill the screen and change its fill colour as appropriate.

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
'allows for pauses in the millisecond range

Sub Flash_routine()
    Dim FillCol As Long
    FillCol = RGB(255, 186, 49)

        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 2000, 1000).Select
    For x = 1 To 2 'phase ie. lightingup, empty
        If x = 1 Then
            IncVal = 0.5
        Else
            IncVal = 0.05
        End If

        For i = 0 To 1 Step IncVal
            With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = FillCol
                If x = 1 Then
                    .Transparency = 1 - i
                Else
                    .Transparency = i
                End If
                .Solid
            End With
            Sleep 50
            'dictates time between successive shape fills
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=3
            ActiveWindow.SmallScroll up:=3
            'refreshes screen view

        Next i
    Next x

        Selection.Delete
End Sub
```

The macro is called by a workbook_open event

However there are a few problems that I would appreciate help with;

- First of all, is this the right approach or is there some screen tint application that I don't know about?
- Assuming it is - my shape doesn't fill the screen. I was under the impression `AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 2000, 1000)` would place my shape in the top left corner (0,0) but it actually gets placed a little way down (Column 1, 3 rows down from wherever my window is currently looking eg. if I'm looking at `F13:X55` it's top corner is placed in `F16`, and the object covers the rest of the cells but not the top 3 rows)
- How do I reference a shape? I didn't know how so I left it as `Selection.ShapeRange.Fill`, but I know selecting is poor VBA practice
- Finally, is scrolling the best way of updating the window view? for some reason it occasionally doesn't even work and the whole macro runs without me seeing anything

I know that's a lot of small points, if an entirely different approach is required they may not even be relevant! Also if changing the excel theme from green to the new colour and gradually back again is possible, that would be really snazzy. Thanks for a solution or any general tips for a newborn VBAer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for shape controls like this:

**UPDATE: Now using your code and the `Sleep` Function... This works for me and is pretty awesome!**

```
Sub Flash_routine()
Dim FillCol As Long
FillCol = RGB(255, 186, 49)

Dim w As Worksheet
Set w = ActiveSheet
Dim s As Shape

Set s = w.Shapes.AddShape(1, 1, 1, 2000, 2000)
For x = 1 To 2 'phase ie. lightingup, empty
    If x = 1 Then
        IncVal = 0.5
    Else
        IncVal = 0.05
    End If

    For i = 0 To 1 Step IncVal
        With s.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = FillCol
            If x = 1 Then
                .Transparency = 1 - i
            Else
                .Transparency = i
            End If
            .Solid
        End With
        Sleep 50
        'dictates time between successive shape fills
        DoEvents
        DoEvents
        'refreshes screen view

    Next i
Next x

    s.Delete
End Sub
```

Obviously just an outline of how it works, first I define `s As Shape` then create the shape within `Set s` so that you can then reference `s` later on to modify it.

Give it a try and feel free to come back. You can use `s.Delete` to remove the shape after your timer / conditions have been met.

Using the 2 DoEvents (for some reason it only worked with 2 of them for me) forces the screen to update showing your changes without the scroll.

I have used `Application.Wait` as I am just more familiar with it.

*FYI - Rectangle is shape 1 so saves you the bother of typing it in full. I put the shape 1 point in horizontal and vertical to get it on the first point of the sheet. I Am unsure whether you can do a full screen tint but perhaps you could affect the shapes opacity if that is desired*

Comment: Still getting the 3 missing rows, I think it may be down to the scroll of 3

Comment: Ah, just saw your update, I'll try do events and see if I still get blank rows

Comment: Haha, no problem best of luck. I'm fairly tired so had to edit as I saw your additional questions after posting the answer up... Oops. I'm happy to play around with it more if you need as I don't have a great deal of work on at the moment.

Comment: @Greedo updated my answer using your code. Let me know if it's what you were looking for as this fades out nicely on my screen

Comment: This, in fact, is "pretty awesome"! I don't have a use for it yet, but will keep it in mind for future uses!

Comment: @Wolfie Yeah I definitely will, I'm thinking as part of save down scripts, if conditions aren't met cancel the save with a red flash fade out, if enough to be saved but not all then amber and a msgbox prompt and green it then save if everything's perfect. Might use it on the staff trackers to force them to record attendance properly haha.

Comment: Yep, `Do Events` instead of scroll solved the 3 missing lines problem. Also `S.Line.Visible = msoFalse` after the with loop to get rid of the border (even better take out of the for...next as this will only slow down the execution I suppose (same with setting the fill colour)) Thanks for the amended code, would've been nice to colour the excel theme too though...